# PHP - Changing session value to change the language

Tags: php, session

I am trying to change the session to a value of "en" or "no" by clicking on a link so that the correct language is being displayed on a website.

I have 2 variables, `$langNO` and `$langEN`. These are variables containing keys and values of each language.

I am using this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {$_SESSION['lang'] = "en";}
if ($_SESSION['lang'] === "no") {$lang = $langNO;}
if ($_SESSION['lang'] === "en") {$lang = $langEN;}
```

`$lang` is related to the strings in the text. 
Example:

```
<h1><?php echo $lang['heading']; ?></h1>
```

To change the session value, I use this in **changelang.php**:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
header("Location:index.php");
```

When I click on `<a href="changelang.php?lang=no">NO</a>` to change the language, it just stays on the default language.

I would love to get some feedback for how this can be solved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the index code a little bit

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {  
    $lang = "en"; 
} else {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}

switch ($_SESSION['lang']) {
    case "en":
        $lang = $langEN;
        break;
    case "no":
        $lang = $langNO;
        break;
}
?>

<a href="changelang.php?lang=no">NO</a>
```

**changelang.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

changelang.php

Set the header() in a function

```
function redirect(url) {
    header('Location: '. url);
}
session_start()
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];

redirect('index.php');
```